# AVPlayer how to set center

Tags: ios, avplayer

Does anyone know a good replacement to setting the center of AVPlayer? I am updating an old project to iOS 9.0 and found that MPMediaPlayer is no longer supported and the app heavily utilized setCenter property from mediaPlayer.

The only property I could find was videoRect, but seems more like getting the frame size more than setting the video at the center of a view.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to center, you dont play the video in full screen?

Comment: There are multiple videos utilizing the screen and uses center point to snap videos to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to reference apple's [example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Listings/Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerView_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016103-Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerView_swift-DontLinkElementID_14).

Make PlayerView inherited from UIView like example and override layerClass() method.

It will align AVPlayer to the center automatically.

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```